# Enable accessibility from command line

Tags: 16.04, xorg, gui

I am looking at the LDTP project for testing and I have an ubuntu linux 16.04 LTS Server with Xorg that autoruns a TK application.

Part of running the application is to use accessibility. Since I don't have access to any of the desktop options (this is being installed via ansible), what is the way to enable the accessibility options that are required?

Comment: you mean some of these options from command line? https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p7Mv.png

Comment: https://ldtp.freedesktop.org/wiki/LDTP_test_scripts_in_python/ "enable assistive technology"

Comment: so you are using GNOME on 16.04?

Comment: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.a11y always-show-universal-access-status`

Comment: I am using lightdm, minimal gnome settings no full gnome desktop with autologin to the tk app.

Comment: gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.a11y always-show-universal-access-status
false

Comment: no, i mean you can set it to true.. i have gone through the link for your project.. as per my understanding this one requires `true`. am i wrong?

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMbxn.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnubC.png or all the options under it need to be active?

Comment: Well it works! I'll need to see the rest if it is available.